# multiplying two normal subgroups is still normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G_i \triangleleft G_{i+1}$ both subgroups of $G$. Let $N$ be a normal group.

Does $G_iN \triangleleft G_{i+1}N$?

Does $(G_iN/N) \triangleleft (G_{i+1}N/N)$?

I know that $q:G\longrightarrow G/N$ preserves normality. Hence if $G_iN \triangleleft G_{i+1}N$ then their quotients would be normal.

I have tried by considering an element in $g\in G_iN$ and $h\in G_{i+1}N$ and trying to find out if $ghg^{-1}\in G_iN$. But I am a bit confused of those multilpication groups. And that is why I can not play with this expression.

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: Edited. @verret

Comment: Have you heard of the second/third isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Yes I do. I have been playing with that expression too. $G_i/(G_i\cap H)\triangleleft G_{i+1}/(G_{i+1}\cap H)$. But still nothing.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things. Is not that I haven't worked on it. Don't you think so. I mean, it is easy to come and coment these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to change the notation to make stuff clearer: Suppose $H\lhd K< G$, and let $N\lhd G$ (so really $H=G_i$ and $K=G_{i+1}$). Then a proof that $HN\lhd KN$ by considering a conjugator is:

Suppose $k\in K$, $h\in H$, and $n, n'\in N$. Firstly, note that
$$n^{-1}k^{-1}(hn')kn=(n^{-1}k^{-1}hkn)\cdot (n^{-1}k^{-1}n'kn)$$
Clearly $(n^{-1}k^{-1}n'kn)\in N$, while $(n^{-1}k^{-1}hkn)\in HN$ by the following:
$$\begin{align*}
k^{-1}hk&\in H\\
\Rightarrow k^{-1}hk\cdot (k^{-1}hk)^{-1}n^{-1}(k^{-1}hk)&\in HN\\
n^{-1}(k^{-1}hk)&\in HN\\
n^{-1}(k^{-1}hk)n&\in HN
\end{align*}
$$
The result follows.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

The first one should be almost immediate, and for the second one:

$$G_iN/N\cong G_i/(G_i\cap N)\;,\;\;\; G_{i+1}/(G_{i+1}\cap N)\cong G_{i+1}N/N$$

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot see how this helps solve the problem. The second one follows directly from the first which, as you say. is straightforward.

Comment: @DerekHolt That isomorphism helps, imo. to see that (1) those quotient groups are well-defined and (2) one is normal in the other. I also think both are more or less straightforward (though this usually depends on the beholder...).  Did I miss anything?

Comment: I don't really see how the isomorphisms help prove that one is normal in the other. (The downvote is not from me.)